# Bazaar version control - github / bitbucket alike solution?

Tags: version-control, bazaar, bazaar-plugins

Is there a bitbucket or github alike hosting service for Bazaar version control?

Answer (score 1):

Consider that the active development isn't exactly thriving (see "[Bzr development stopped](https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/bazaar/2012q4/075330.html)"), with a [2.6 released in August 2013, more than a year after the 2.6b2 (July 2012)](https://launchpad.net/bzr/+announcements).

That could explain that there don't seem to be a service similar to GitHub or BitBucket for bazaar repos (beside [launchpad.net](https://launchpad.net/), which don't have all the features of a GitHub).

Even CodeBase, which [announced Bazaar support in 2011](http://www.codebasehq.com/blog/codebase-v4-is-ready), don't list Bazaar [in its features](http://www.codebasehq.com/features) today.